# How do I cover one div with another via z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Referring in this instance

I can not get the div with `id="covered"` on top of the div with `id="cover"` simply by using the `z-index`.

Is there any other solution?

Code from http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jhgtf :

HTML:

```
<div id="cover"></div>
<div id="covered"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#cover{
  position:fixed;
  width:800px;
  background:black;
  height:350px;
  z-index:10;
}
#covered{
  width:80px;
  background:yellow;
  height:50px;
  z-index:11;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify a `position` on `#covered`:

```
#cover{
  position:fixed;
  width:800px;
  background:black;
  height:350px;
  z-index:10;
}
#covered{
  position: fixed;
  width:80px;
  background:yellow;
  height:50px;
  z-index:11;
}
```

[**CodePen example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLJhx)

Elements with `static` (default) positioning are not affected by z-index - only positioned elements with `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute` positioning are.  Which of those you should use is dependent on context.

[**Official z-index specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)

Answer (score 1):

```
#covered{
  position:relative;
  width:80px;
  background:yellow;
  height:50px;
  z-index:11;
}
```